# Need help - FB Like button does not post to wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Hello fellow community members,

I was unable to find a helpful answer, so I will give this a try: I recently developed a website that has a FB "Recommend" (same as "Like") button implemented. I have never dealt with this before, hence my complete lack of knowledge.

Now, I implemented the code the FB developer's Like page (--> http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) creates correctly into the website (both the script and the DIV-tag, yet something that is not automatically generated seems to be missing and needs to be added for the button to work correctly. **It currently does not post to the FB wall.**

Upon doing a debugging check, I received the following results: [...]

Unfortunately, I have no clue what to do with that data. **How** and **where** exactly in the HTML code do I implement those missing TAGS and PROPERTIES? Any help would be highly appreciated...

Kind regards & many thanks in advance, :-)

Doc

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing the Open Graph `meta` tags. Those go into the `head` of your page.

Facebook has a [generator](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#oggenerator) to help you create the tags, but you'll need to add them into your markup.

Comment: Colm, you were right, of course, and after googling to figure out how to find my FB ID I was able to fix the issue in no time! Many, many thanks for your quick and accurate response! <3